# Trying to install rJava using R terminal

Tags: r, rjava

I've tried looking at all the other questions about this, and none of them worked for me. I'm trying to use a package in R that requires rJava. I downloaded JDK version 11.0.7 and I also have R version 3.5.1. I had also downloaded jre8u251 some blog post told me to download. I've also tried all sorts of commands using "sudo" but none of those worked either. Any idea on how to proceed now? I'm using a MacBook. I am wondering if I just need to delete everything and reinstall but I don't see how I could have messed up installing things.

Comment: Have you tried a mac specific approach, Eg. [like this](https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rJava/) ?

Comment: It's also important to know the Java compatibility for other packages you intend to use with `rJava`, given your version of R. For example, The R 4.0.1 version of the `XLConnect` package only works with Java 8 through Java 11.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sudo commands you have tried?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/ and here https://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/